# How to get a sorted result in iBatis?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, ibatis

I have a table mgr_employee with 2 columns managerName, teamEmployee.
Although I do a sort in sql I get unsorted resultMap in java.
 How can I get a sorted map? Why does iBatis mix up the resultMap?

```
<resultMap id="s_filter_defaults_ResultMap" class="java.util.HashMap">
  <result property="key" column="managerName"/>
  <result property="value" column="count"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="mCount" parameterClass="java.util.HashMap" resultMap="mcount_ResultMap">
    <![CDATA[
     select managerName, count(teamEmployee) AS count
      from mgr_employee
      group by managerName 
      order by managerName;
    ]]>
</select>
```

Java code to call the above sql:

```
Map<String,Long> mCountMap = getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForMap("mCount", "", "key", "value");
```

mCountMap is not sorted as was expected due to the "order by" clause in the sql.
Any comments/suggestion, how to get the resultMap sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be with the Java types used. To need to **query for a list**, not for a Map, because the Java HashMap (I suppose this is what the query will return) doesn't have support for sorting.
See the [SqlMapDaoTemplate#queryForList()](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/user/com/ibatis/dao/client/template/SqlMapDaoTemplate.html) methods that should return what you need.

Comment: Can you copy the fix here. How did you get Key value pair using List?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is due to the fact that the Map is not an ordered structure: the keys of the map are stored in the order of their hash codes. What you would need to do is to put the keys of the map into a vector and then sort them (or have SQL sort them for you and then insert them into a vector). Then you could iterate over vector and access the map by the keys.

Answer (score 1):

A [`java.util.LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) will ensure iteration in the order that items were added, try using that class instead of just a plain `HashMap`, which does not maintain iteration order.

Comment: this did not work. I had to do getQueryList as suggested by A. Ionescu