# IBatis + Java: Retrieving HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, ibatis

How can I retrieve a HashMap using IBatis. I have a select for two values, and I want to maps this in a key-value map.

Someone has faced the same problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The "two values" are two records (each with one column), or two columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this Question:
[How to get a sorted result in iBatis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122979/how-to-get-a-sorted-result-in-ibatis/3123013#3123013)

The user there gets a HashMap but needs a list, hence my answer there.

So you can use the example in that Question description to retrieve a HashMap as he did.