# Retrieve Key-Value Pairs as Map

Tags: java, datamapper, ibatis

I'm trying to retrieve two columns from the DB with iBatis.  I want to do it as a Map, such that `resultMap.get(col1) == col2Obj`.

The same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3353526/684934), but the posted solution won't work for me, and fails with the error: `Cannot cast List as Map`.  I am using iBatis 2.3.4.  (Is this feature available in this version?  I can't seem to find the relevant documentation.)

My statement map:

```
<resultMap id="countMap" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <result property="key" column="KEY" />
    <result property="value" column="VALUE" />
</resultMap>
<select id="getCounts" resultMap="countMap" parameterClass="map">
SELECT
    TYPE AS KEY,
    SUM(VAL) AS VALUE
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE REGDATE BETWEEN #start_date# and #end_date#
GROUP BY TYPE
</select>
```

The actual query returns:

```
|| KEY || VALUE ||
|| 4   || 304   ||
```

Calling `.toString()` on the Map that returns:

```
{"key" : "4", "value" : "304" }
```

Since the keyset consists of {"key", "value"}, the resultMap doesn't appear to be doing what I want it to do.  When I call the query with parameters that would result in more than 1 row, I get the error.

I am using `sqlMapClient.queryForMap("mymap.getCounts", args);` to execute the query.

Comment: Which iBatis method are you using to run the query? Can you post the code you're using? Can you also post the Exception, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wups, I got it.

I needed to use

```
sqlMapClient.queryForMap("mymap.getCounts", args, "key", "value");
```